# return boolean in ASP.NET controller MVC to compare in if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible return a boolean value from ASP.NET controller. I have written this:

```
public class HomeController : Controllewe
{
    public ActionResult Check()
    {
        var check = new CheckAD();
        if (check.CheckSecurityWithAD())
        {
            ...
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            return Json(false);
        }
   }
 }
```

And I want to compare the returned value in a if statment. I tried in this way :

```
@if (@Html.Action("Check", "Home") == true)
{
    ....
}
```

But I get the error `cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type string and boolean`. How can I resolve? Thanks

Comment: What does `@Html.Action` do?

Comment: `return Json(true);` When you call that endpoint directly, check the payload being returned in Chrome Dev Tools. What does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

`Json(..)` returns a string. Try on your View like:

```
@if (@Html.Action("Check", "Home") == "true")
{
    ....
}
```

or

```
@if (bool.Parse(@Html.Action("Check", "Home")) == true)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: if I try with the first method I get `Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' and 'string', candidates are: bool ==(string, string)`. If I use `bool.Parse()` I get `Argument type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'`